# Ler email mais recente - JavaMail

Tags: java

Dei uma procurada por aqui mas sem sucesso. Alguém sabe como buscar o email mais recente usando o `JavaMail`? O que eu estou usando puxa todos os emails. Meu código:

```
        try {

            campolog.setContentType("text/html");

            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);

            Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("pop.gmail.com", "email@gmail.com", "senha");

//            javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
//            for (javax.mail.Folder folder : folders) {
//                if ((folder.getType() & javax.mail.Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {
//                    System.out.println(folder.getFullName() + ": " + folder.getMessageCount());
//                }
//            }

            Folder pastaEmail = store.getFolder("SMS");
            pastaEmail.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message[] mensagens = pastaEmail.getMessages();
            System.out.println("Total de Emails: " + mensagens.length);

            for (int i = 0, n = mensagens.length; i < n; i++) {
                    Message mensagem = mensagens[i];
                    //campolog.append("---------------------------------");
                    //campolog.append("Email Nº " + (i + 1));
                    //campolog.append("Assunto: " + mensagem.getSubject());
                    //campolog.setText("De: " + mensagem.getFrom()[0]);
                    campolog.setText("Mensagem: " + mensagem.getContent().toString());
            }

            pastaEmail.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Então, nesse caso eu precisaria ter a "posição" exata do email. Exemplo: Email1, Email2....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca usei, mas lendo a documentação da API:

- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getSortedMessages-com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm:A-

Creio que tenha que usar `getSortedMessages` então você ordenaria por data, assim:

```
SortTerm[] termos = new SortTerm[1];

termos[0] = SortTerm.DATE; //Pode adicionar mais critérios de ordem adicionando termos[1], termos[2], etc

Folder pastaEmail = store.getFolder("SMS");
pastaEmail.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

Message[] mensagens = ((IMAPFolder) pastaEmail).getSortedMessages(termos);
```

> O código fiz seguindo o exemplo desta resposta do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994431/1518921

Então para ler a primeira mensagem ao invés do `for` faria apenas uma checagem assim:

```
if (mensagens.length > 0) {
    mensagens[0].getContent(); //Faça algo com o conteudo retornado
} else {
    //Não há mensagens
}
```

O `SortTerm.DATE` vai ordenar pela data (e hora) do envio da mensagem, assim você vai pegar pela hora que o remetente enviou, mas se precisar da hora da "chegada", quando chegou a sua caixa de email, então use:

- https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/SortTerm.html#ARRIVAL

Assim:

```
SortTerm[] termos = new SortTerm[1];

termos[0] = SortTerm.ARRIVAL;

Folder pastaEmail = store.getFolder("SMS");
pastaEmail.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Eu nunca usei, como disse, só li a documentação e a resposta, mas creio que isto ordene como o esperado, no entanto se estiver em ordem inversa, por exemplo retornar a mensagem mais antiga no `mensagens[0].getContent();` então basta inverter pegando o ultimo item de `Message[] mensagens`, assim:

```
if (mensagens.length > 0) {
    final int ultimaMensagem = mensagens.length - 1;
    mensagens[ultimaMensagem].getContent();
} else {
    //Não há mensagens
}
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
if (mensagens.length > 0) {
    mensagens[ mensagens.length - 1 ].getContent();
} else {
    //Não há mensagens
}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado mesmo! Eu aproveitei pra procurar na documentação como eu tratava o email, retirando algumas partes. Não consegui achar nada sobre. Não precisa me dar a resposta, mas você viu algo disso por lá? Ou pode me dar dicas sobre como pesquisar?

Comment: @AbnerRodrigues depende do que quer retirar do email para ser exibido, se puder dizer eu leio melhor a doc e tento colocar como exemplo ;)

Comment: Olha, eu recebo o email assim:

`Mensagem: *** EMAIL AUTOMATICO, POR FAVOR NAO RESPONDA ***  Ola abnerodrigs Voce recebeu uma resposta.  Numero do Celular: 11982743910 SMS que voce enviou: Ola, o visitante: Fulanochegou! Podemos autorizar a entrada? Digite 1 para sim ou 2 para nao. Mensagem Respondida pelo Celular: 1`

Eu queria deixar apenas a parte "Respondida pelo Celular: 1"

Comment: @AbnerRodrigues essa parte vai ter que usar regex, pode criar uma nova pergunta explicando que quer extrair de uma string essa parte, ai vou formular uma nova resposta, para não misturar os assuntos. Por favor marca essa resposta como correta, obrigado! Se não souber como fazer leia este link: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: Eu que agradeço!!

Comment: @AbnerRodrigues assim que fizer a pergunta, copia o link e me manda aqui pra eu responder :)

Comment: Vixi, não vai rolar. Eu atingi o limite de questões (Uma por dia é sacanagem) e precisarei esperar mais `6` dias para perguntar de novo... Mas muito obrigado, vou tentar dar uma pesquisada por aqui. Muito obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: @AbnerRodrigues vou te mandar aqui o código, só preciso testar e já te mando

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @AbnerRodrigues pronto, fiz um exemplo para você estudar como pegar a parte da string necessária: https://repl.it/@inphinit/extract-phone-regexjava

Comment: muito obrigado cara, eu te amo! Hahahaha. VALEU MESMO <3